# tapku calendar header error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, header-files, tapku

I'm creating a tapku calendar project similar to the tutorial, however I keep getting an error in my header file. My header file looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <TapkuLibrary/TapkuLibrary.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *dataArray;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *dataDictionary;
@end
```

The error says : `TapkuLibrary/TapkuLibrary.h file not found`.

I have imported the files as indicated in the tapku tutorial, do you know why I'm still getting this message?

Comment: did you added the tapkulibrary to your project ? A file extension .a